# Tracking Device Usage via Google APIs

Tags: api

Is there a way to directly tie device usage to a user, date, and time?

I can use `chromeosdevices.list` to get (among a lot of other things) a device id, a list of recent users, and a list of times the device was recently used.

I can't seem to find a way to map a user directly to a device.  for example, I can't seem to be able to pull data saying that device A was used/accessed/logged into at time B by user C.

Is this possible, or am I chasing my tail?